# Facing issue with restarting logstash everytime changes made to filebeat conf

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am new to elk stack . As per my understanding to make logs getting read from filebeat to logstash to kibana , below are steps.

Server setting : I  have filebeat , logstash , kibana configured on different nodes.

Steps :

```
1. First start logstash.
2. Then start filebeat .
3. Registry is created on filebeat path / var/lob/filebeat/registry giving offset value once logstash acknowledges that data is read, otherwise it remains empty.
```

Problem Statement : Changes are made to one of the logs conf  . 
eg : logstash-test-log.conf .

Note : There are other logs conf also being read .

```
Q1) In order to get the new changes being read I have to stop logstash and then restart . Is it going to impact the reading of other logs conf ?

Q2) Need to restart filebeat as well . Is this correct way ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: 
Set the `config.reload.automatic: true` configuration on logstash.yml. So, logstash will not be required to stop running and thus affecting the remaining pipelines. It will be monitoring the pipelines and will trigger a reload when changes happens by itself.

Q2: Yes.